# How to remove white spaces on either side of '=' sign?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string `String string = "attr1 = 45 attr2 =\"82\"";`

I am trying to remove all whitespace characters on either side of the `=` sign.

So that for example my output looks like:

`attr1=45 attr="82"`

I have tried the following:

```
String string = "attr1 = 45 attr2 =\"82\"";
string = string.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

I get the following output: `attr1=45attr2="82"`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code which you tried that did not work.

Comment: @JamesMontagne there is the code

Comment: Your current code replaces **every** space not just the ones next to an equal sign. Step back and think about it for a minute. How do you create a regex that matches any amount of whitespace followed by an equal sign followed by any amount of whitespace. (If this stumps you, think about writing a regex that just matches an equal sign.)

Comment: `string = string.replaceAll("\\s*=\\s*", "=");`

Comment: @hwnd I figured that a while ago. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to replace all spaces, but only these that are around `=`. Try with

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\s*=\\s*", "=");
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you cannot do this with just one regex since regexes are designed to **match** strings, not **modify** them. Regexes are often used with other tools to perform the later task. In particular, you can use `String.replace()` or `String.replaceAll()` with a *very* simple regex to accomplish your task.

**Edit:**

If you are still stumped, step back for a minute and think: How would you replace an equal sign with an asterisk, for example? Now can you modify that to do what you actually want?